Mouse cursor moving on its own
This problem happened to me a few years ago, and then disappeared for unknown reasons.  But now it's back.
When I right click in most applications (but not all), the mouse cursor, which starts out in the upper left corner of the resulting dialog box, slowly starts moving down and to the right in a jerky fashion, even if I'm not touching the mouse.  Sometimes the cursor will eventually stop moving, but most of the time it won't.  If I then move my mouse in a different direction, the cursor movement will change to that direction, usually with a slight lag, but will then continue its jerky motion in the new direction.
If I don't do anything else, this behavior will continue for the rest of the session, making right-clicking useless.  I can temporarily avoid this problem by selecting the item I was going to right click on with the left mouse button and then typing Shift+F10.  But it's very difficult to get the mouse cursor in the correct position to perform this action, especially since it continues to move.
If I lock the screen, then usually (but not always) the mouse movement returns to normal on the lock screen.  But once I unlock the screen, the jerky movement returns.
The one thing that fixes this is logging out and logging back in.  (Rebooting also works, of course, but is not necessary).  If I log out and log back in, cursor movement returns to normal until I right click again.
This problem happens with various different mice from various manufacturers, both wired and wireless, and happens on all USB ports.
This is happening on a Windows 10 Pro desktop (custom built) with all the latest updates, including the latest mouse drivers.  The previous occurrence of this problem was also on a Windows 10 Pro desktop (custom built) with all the latest updates, although it was a different machine.  There's nothing I did that I can think of that could reasonably have triggered this - no new software or hardware, etc.  And closing out all the apps on my desktop has no effect.  What is happening here, and how do I fix it?

A couple of weeks after I posted my last comment, I finally found and solved the root problem.  As I have now been running over two months with this solution and the problem has not recurred, I feel confident enough that I have solved it to post the cause and the fix.
The cause of the problem was the program Asutype, which is an excellent background spell checker and corrector that also does many other things, such as expanding abbreviations.  But to the best of my knowledge, it didn't do anything with the mouse.  Nevertheless, since I had eliminated all obvious possible sources of my problem, I decided to look at Asutype more closely.
When I looked at the Options window, under the Advanced selection, I found the problem.  There was a setting named UseGestures that was set to "Yes."  This sounded like mouse gestures, although I had never used these.  (I later found where these were optionally used in the program.)  Once I set this option to "No," my problem with the moving cursor disappeared permanently.

Does it happen in SAFE mode?

If it does, look for a device such as touch pad, tablet, etc. that might be sending mouse messages. A touch pad that has become damp can cause that issue.
If not, look to an add-on that intercepts mouse messages, such as AutoHotkey, RemoteMouse, etc.


That did it!  As I was rather sure that this was a software problem and I had no other devices that could be sending mouse inputs, and as I have an AutoHotkey script that runs constantly in the background, even though it has no explicit mouse commands, I focused on the AutoHotkey script.  Disabling it made the problem disappear.  But what was the problem, since the script looked fine?  I decided it was most likely a corrupted executable.  I recompiled the script, started it, and it's been fine ever since.  Thanks!

It seems I spoke too soon.  I rebooted my computer today, and the problem returned -except worse.  Disabling AutoHotkey didn't help.  Furthermore, whereas the problem was triggered before only by the right mouse button, it is now triggered by any mouse button, essentially making it impossible to work.  I can't even turn on Mouse Keys, as that requires mouse clicks.  Yet here I am in Safe Mode, where everything works perfectly.  Any suggestions are welcome.

If it works correctly in Safe Mode, then it definitely is a software issue. Once the issue occurs, open Task Manager, and, on the Details tab, look for any odd process. You can kill a process to see if it fixes the issue -- yes, Windows might crash if the wrong process is killed, but just reboot. BTW, is Remote Desktop on? Could be an open connection causing the issue.

What you suggest sounds quite reasonable, and I had actually started doing that.  However, as the mouse had gotten to the point where it couldn't even be used to select items, this meant manipulating the Task Manager only through the keyboard.  This is doable, but rather time consuming, especially since I have several hundred processes running.  So I stopped doing this and tried Safe Mode, where the problem went away.  Interestingly, it didn't come back when I rebooted this time; normally, rebooting has no effect.  I'll resume the killing processes method if the problem returns.

It turns out that using Task Manager to kill off processes was not a viable solution after all.  Normally, I have no problem killing processes with Task Manager.  But once this problem arises, many processes simply throw up a "Permission Denied" error window when I try to kill them.  So I went back just to figuring out what was going on.  (Solution follows.)

I finally discovered that when I had both PowerToys and a timer called XNote running, the problem arose as soon as I right-clicked on XNote.  Without PowerToys, XNote worked fine, and without XNote, there was no problem.  So I have simply been using both programs, but using Shift-F10 instead of Right-Click to set and reset XNote.  This worked fine for many days, until right now.  (Continued)

When composing this message, I right-clicked on an unknown word to add it to the dictionary, and the original problem returned.  I started closing windows in preparation for logging out, but when I got to my browser, the mouse was working fine, which enabled me to finish writing this.  Other things are failing in typical ways, though, so I'll have to end up logging out and logging back in anyway.  The next step is just disabling XNote so that it never loads; does anyone know of a similar stopwatch program that works well?  BTW, this whole problem started after a Microsoft security update.
